# What is the problem with this flask running?

Tags: python, flask

I put this code (python) in my container:

[image]

and then I ran

FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0

And I got this error:

[image]

If you know what the problem is- It will help me a lot,
thank you!

Comment: That seems to be an image file and not Python code; you can't directly run it.  Could you edit the question and replace the images with the actual source code and error output?  If this is a Docker-related question don't forget to also include the text of your image's Dockerfile and the command you're using to launch the container.

Comment: Try `import app` from the Python command line. If you don't succeed, flask cannot import it either.